# In what cases BitmapFactory.Options.inPreferredConfig not working?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I'm trying to decode a bitmap from an `InputStream` using `BitmapFactory.decodeStream`, and I want to receive the bitmap in `ARGB_8888`, so I used `BitmapFactory.Options.inPreferredConfig = ARGB_8888` but some of my users somehow manage to load a bitmap in a different configuration (`RGBA_F16`), which makes sense giving the fact that the name of the field is **Preferred**, But why is that? In what cases Android can't load a bitmap in the `inPreferredConfig`? the source code is not very clear about that. my solution will be to convert the bitmap to `ARGB_8888` using `Bitmap.copy`, or `Canvas.drawBitmap`, but before that, I want to understand why it happened.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you in control over the actual image, or is it an image that comes from an arbitrary source (e.g., downloaded by the user)? If the image can be from anywhere, perhaps there are issues with certain image types, or images with certain properties.

Comment: @CommonsWare users can import images into the app, so I have no control about that... and I don't think that the image file is corrupted, because users can import images using import wizard that works fine.

Comment: I did not mean to imply that the images were corrupted, just unusual in some way.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of `BitmapFactory.Options` describes the role of `inPreferredConfig` like this: If this is non-null, the decoder will try to decode into this color space. Although you specify Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, it will eventually be adjusted according to the image file itself.

[The following code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:external/skia/src/codec/SkAndroidCodec.cpp;l=115;bpv=1;bpt=1) illustrates how the color space of the image is determined:

```
SkColorType SkAndroidCodec::computeOutputColorType(SkColorType requestedColorType) {
    bool highPrecision = fCodec->getEncodedInfo().bitsPerComponent() > 8;
    switch (requestedColorType) {
        case kARGB_4444_SkColorType:
            return kN32_SkColorType;
        case kN32_SkColorType:
            break;
        case kAlpha_8_SkColorType:
            // Fall through to kGray_8.  Before kGray_8_SkColorType existed,
            // we allowed clients to request kAlpha_8 when they wanted a
            // grayscale decode.
        case kGray_8_SkColorType:
            if (kGray_8_SkColorType == this->getInfo().colorType()) {
                return kGray_8_SkColorType;
            }
            break;
        case kRGB_565_SkColorType:
            if (kOpaque_SkAlphaType == this->getInfo().alphaType()) {
                return kRGB_565_SkColorType;
            }
            break;
        case kRGBA_F16_SkColorType:
            return kRGBA_F16_SkColorType;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // F16 is the Android default for high precision images.
    return highPrecision ? kRGBA_F16_SkColorType : kN32_SkColorType;
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30293945)